# Adding constraints programmatically in UIView with UITextView

Tags: swift, autolayout, uitextview

I added constraints programmatically in my UITextView, but trailing and bottom constraints are not working correctly. others work fine.
I think UITextView frame size is not correct.

I just want to add margin in my UITextView programmatically.

My code is

```
    let textView = UITextView()
    self.view.addSubview(textView)

    var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    constraintTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.view,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 10)
    constraints.append(constraintTop)

    constraintBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.view,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 10)
    constraints.append(constraintBottom)

    constraintLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.view,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 10)
    constraints.append(constraintLeft)

    constraintRight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.view,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 10)
    constraints.append(constraintRight)

    self.view.addConstraints(constraints)
```

Comment: @EICaptain actually, I'm not understanding programmatic autolayout. if you are, how do you make margin?

Comment: Try `-10` for your constant for your trailing and bottom constraints.

Comment: @vacawama I could. thank you so much. I thought as same as storyboard.

Comment: In the Storyboard, the order of the items is reversed for those 2 constraints which is the other way to fix it:  set `item` to `self.view` and `toItem:` to `textView` for the trailing and bottom constraints.

Comment: Swift now supports layout anchors, which are far more concise and pleasant to use, satisfying basic layout needs like adapting a subview to parent boundaries or safe areas, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this in one of two ways:

1. Change the `constant` to `-10` for your bottom and trailing constraints.

**or**

2. Switch the order of the `item:` and `toItem:` values in the bottom and trailing constraints.  That is, make `item: self.view` and `toItem: textView` for the bottom and trailing constraints.  This is how it is done if you set the constraints in the StoryBoard.