# UIViewController subview incorrect size/layout when using UIViewControllerRepresentable (without storyboard)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm trying to build and integrate to a custom UIViewController with a tapRecognizer and an UITextView.

The issue I face is that the UITextView display part of the text off screen and I don't know what is causing this! I expect something simple or maybe including more classes but I haven't found anything pointing me in the right direction yet.

The size / position of a UITextView is working well when using UIViewRepresentable and a UITextView but not with a UIViewController / UIViewControllerRepresentable and a UITextView inside it for some reasons (see example bellow with both for comparison).

Here is the code of the test app I have:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct TestingView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            WrappedUIViewController().padding()
            Spacer()
            WrappedUITextView(myText: "This is a long text to see if the word wrap work in this case better I hope so but I don't know. Is it? I hope it is, ! Do you? I do! Hope you do too, do you?").padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct WrappedUITextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let myText: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextViewPlus {
        let view = UITextViewPlus()
        view.isScrollEnabled = true
        view.isEditable = false
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.font = UIFont(name: "Time New Roman", size: 20)
        
        view.isOpaque = false
        view.text = "WrappedUITextView \(myText)"
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextViewPlus, context: Context) {}
}

struct WrappedUIViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = CustomUIViewController
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CustomUIViewController {
        return CustomUIViewController()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CustomUIViewController, context: Context) {}
}

class CustomUIViewController: UIViewController {
    var textView: UITextView = UITextView()
    var tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(recognizer:)))
        self.textView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        self.textView.isEditable = false
        self.textView.isSelectable = false
        self.textView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        self.textView.text = """
            This is some text that will need to be displayed on multiple lines as it's longer than the screen size, will it wrapp correctly?
            This is a great testing app
                        
            This is the end of this textView content
            Here is a Potato
            """
        
        self.textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        self.textView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        view.addSubview(self.textView)
        
    }
    
    @objc func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location: CGPoint = recognizer.location(in: textView)
        let position: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y)
        let tapPosition: UITextPosition = textView.closestPosition(to: position)!
        guard let textRange: UITextRange = textView.tokenizer.rangeEnclosingPosition(tapPosition, with: UITextGranularity.word, inDirection: UITextDirection(rawValue: 1)) else { return }
        
        let tappedWord: String = textView.text(in: textRange) ?? ""
        print("tapped word -> \(tappedWord)")
    }
    
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        textView.sizeThatFits(self.view.bounds.size)
        textView.sizeToFit()
    }
}
```

The green textView is not wrapping the text properly or has a size that goes off screen for some reasons:
[image: The green textView is not wrapping the text properly]

I'm new to swift and IOS so I would not be surprised if I do something wrong, any help is welcome!

EDIT: in case the code of the other file would help resolve this (I doubt it though):

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct testAppApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Text("Test App")
            TestingView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is driving me crazy ! Is there no other way than to give a fix frame to my UITextView to ensure it doesn't goes outside the screen?

Comment: I think this is because in UIViewController  you need to add constraints to properly align your UITextView, either programmatically or on storyboard

Comment: You gave me something interesting sadly adding constraint seems to cause more issues. I get conflicts with existing constraints. I used this post to add constraints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33072969/adding-constraints-programmatically-in-uiview-with-uitextview

Comment: I have made changes to your code and posted it as an answer, hopefully that should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have made changes to you CustomViewController class and added constraints to your textview to allow it to align properly. Methods and lines of code i have added are commented

You have to tell Auto Layout how you want your view to be aligned and positioned otherwise everything will be chaotic.

```
class CustomUIViewController: UIViewController {
    var textView: UITextView = UITextView()
    var tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(recognizer:)))
        self.textView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        self.textView.isEditable = false
        self.textView.isSelectable = false
        self.textView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        self.textView.text = """
            This is some text that will need to be displayed on multiple lines as it's longer than the screen size, will it wrapp correctly?
            This is a great testing app
                        
            This is the end of this textView content
            Here is a Potato
            """
        
        self.textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        self.textView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        self.textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false //ADDED: allows view to obey Auto Layout constraints.
        view.addSubview(self.textView)
        
        addConstraints() //ADDED: method for invoking constraints
        
    }
    
    func addConstraints(){
        let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide //safe area layout - esp for devices with notch
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor), //textview's top anchor = that of parent view
            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor),
            textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200), //gave textview a constant height
            textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    @objc func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location: CGPoint = recognizer.location(in: textView)
        let position: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y)
        let tapPosition: UITextPosition = textView.closestPosition(to: position)!
        guard let textRange: UITextRange = textView.tokenizer.rangeEnclosingPosition(tapPosition, with: UITextGranularity.word, inDirection: UITextDirection(rawValue: 1)) else { return }
        
        let tappedWord: String = textView.text(in: textRange) ?? ""
        print("tapped word -> \(tappedWord)")
    }
    
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        textView.sizeThatFits(self.view.bounds.size)
        textView.sizeToFit()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this code. coming from swiftUI I'm finding it hard to wrap my head around the "old way of doing things". I'll play around what you gave me to see if I can make the view to wrapjust the text and nothing more!

Comment: Glad i could help @Slamit, if the above solves your issue, please consider marking it as the answer

Comment: I don't manage to have the view wrap around the text while staying on screen with constrains :(. I'll continue to play around hopping I might manage it :-)

Answer (score 0):

After multiple iterations I managed to get something that would work, actually 2 options to solve this:

1. Changing "view.addSubview(self.textView)" to "view. = self.textView" in viewDidLoad. I'm not sure what this change but with this I have the UITextview bound ajusted by the system.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        view = self.textView
    }
```

2. the second and most likely "better" solution: set a frame to my UITextView inside viewDidLoad. When "textView.sizeToFit()" the height is then addapted while the width is maintained to what I wanted:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        self.textView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 10000)
        ...
        view.addSubview(self.textView)
    }
```